# DataGridView- не срабатывает с первого раза список в ячейке

Tags: c#, winforms

Суть проблемы - есть DataGridView, строка в нем состоит из выпадающих списков с заранее определенными значениями. новые строки добавляются автоматом самим DataGridView по окончании ввода данных в предыдущую строку. Новая строка добавилась, я хочу сделать выбор из выпадающего списка, щелкаю на нем мышью - и ноль реакции, щелкаю ее еще раз - раскрывается список и я выбираю нужное значение, все работает.
Вопрос- как сделать так чтобы список раскрывался и давал возможность выбора по первому щелчку мыши а не со второго?

Comment: Видимо, по первому клику подгружаются данные в список, а вот второй клик уже получается рабочим. Как у вас список наполняется? Покажите код.

Comment: Да, есть такая особенность у кастомных Datagridview-ячеек

Comment: Спасибо за ответы